# Adding DTD info to xml using DOM

Tags: java, dom, stax

I am using DOM to create an XML file and using StAX to parse another xml to get data selectively to write.

I am stuck at a point where I have the DTD event from Stax but i dont know how to write it to DOM document.

```
Document doc = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().newDocument();

while (r.hasNext()) {
            int eventType = r.next();

            Node child;

            switch (eventType) {
            case XMLStreamConstants.CDATA:
                child = doc.createCDATASection(r.getText());
                break;
            case XMLStreamConstants.DTD:
            //??? - what shoould come here?
            break;
```

`r` is XMLEventReader object

Comment: If you're converting XML to XML, it might be easier to use XSLT

Comment: its a big xml file, i have to use StAX for parsing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer finally.

Doctype is added when transforming the file.

```
 Transformer tFormer = 
  TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
//  Set system id
  tFormer.setOutputProperty(
  OutputKeys.DOCTYPE_SYSTEM, "systmId");

  Source source = new DOMSource(doc);
  Result result = new StreamResult(System.out);
  tFormer.transform(source, result);
```